# Stramge Error on Numerical Strings: NumberFormatException

Tags: java, string, numberformatexception

I'm getting a strange number format exception. I understand that if there are strange characters when I try to create a new Integer wrapper object, it won't work but it seems that my input strings are normal numerical strings. Are there other reasons I could be getting this error?

```
systemtest:
    [junit] Running simpledb.systemtest.ScanTest
    [junit] Testsuite: simpledb.systemtest.ScanTest
    [junit] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Time elapsed: 0.097 sec
    [junit] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Time elapsed: 0.097 sec
    [junit] 
    [junit] Testcase: testSmall took 0.025 sec
    [junit]     Caused an ERROR
    [junit] For input string: "4386131530"
    [junit] java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4386131530"
    [junit]     at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    [junit]     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:484)
    [junit]     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:514)
    [junit]     at simpledb.HeapPageId.hashCode(HeapPageId.java:44)

...

[junit] Testcase: testCache took 0.029 sec
    [junit]     Caused an ERROR
    [junit] For input string: "8140111260"
    [junit] java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8140111260"
    [junit]     at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    [junit]     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:484)
    [junit]     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:514)
    [junit]     at simpledb.HeapPageId.hashCode(HeapPageId.java:44)
    [junit]     at simpledb.BufferPool.getPage(BufferPool.java:70)
    [junit]     at simpledb.HeapFile$HFTupleIterator.retrieveTuples(HeapFile.java:200)
    [junit]     at simpledb.HeapFile$HFTupleIterator.open(HeapFile.java:141)
    [junit]     at simpledb.SeqScan.open(SeqScan.java:92)
    [junit]     at simpledb.systemtest.SystemTestUtil.matchTuples(SystemTestUtil.java:121)
    [junit]     at simpledb.systemtest.SystemTestUtil.matchTuples(SystemTestUtil.java:107)
    [junit]     at simpledb.systemtest.SystemTestUtil.matchTuples(SystemTestUtil.java:100)
    [junit]     at simpledb.systemtest.ScanTest.testCache(ScanTest.java:99)
    [junit]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your numbers are too large to fit in an integer variable.  Integers of this magnitude fit in a `long`, however.  Either change the declaration to `long` (or possibly `BigDecimal`), or use smaller numbers <= `Integer.MAX_VALUE`;